# C# Connect ItemID(database) to ComboBox

Tags: c#

```
string sname = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Item"));
comboBox2.Items.Add(sname);
```

it is the correct pattern of adding the database in combobox, but i dont know of how to convert it to int, because im getting my ItemID
i appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Sorry ! I am not fully understanding your question. What you want to convert to int ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to read the `ItemId` column value from your sql query result set, which is of type int, you can try this.

```
int itemId = myReader.GetInt32(myReader.GetOrdinal("ItemId"));
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following to convert a string to int:

```
int newIntVariable = int.Parse(yourStringVariable);
```